# Why msi file size is bigger than main application

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I found that the size of msi file is 69.0 MB although the size my main application is 1.5 MB, so where all this size goes for?!

Comment: Microsofts statement to this behaviour is in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371150(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the previous poster I would recommend using [Orca](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/orca-exe) to inspect the package. It is included in the Windows Installer SDK.
You have to know what it is required for your application to run. Mostly you need the VC++ runtime, data access components, 3rd party dlls. If your application is managed you can add ~20 mb for the .NET 2.0 runtime. The .NET 3.5 redistributable ia about ~200Mb.  The client profile is about ~70mb, which maybe answers your question.
Consider using web downloaders, which would download and install .NET runtime on demand.

Comment: Web downloaders aren't always well received in a corporate environment (and MSI file size wouldn't be a concern), however if you're distributing a small app via the internet then it's probably the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

***Prerequisites & Runtimes***: My guess is that you have included a large number of *merge modules*, *runtime packages* or *prerequisites* such as the `.NET framework` in your MSI. A prerequisite like `Crystal Reports` is a common way to bloat your package.

***MSI File Fragmentation***: Another possibility is that you have **saved the MSI many times**. MSI files are COM-structured storage files, and they don't feature any "defragmentation" of the internal streams. To determine if this is the problem, just open the MSI in Orca and do a Save As... If the file size is reduced, the problem (or part of it) was caused by file fragmentation.

***Old-Style Office Files***: Note that the "Save As..." behavior is the same as in Office documents. When doing Save As on a Word document, for example, the file size may be drastically reduced. The cause of this is the "defragmentation" that occurs when the file content is streamed to a new file with no fragmentation. Newer versions of Office uses a Zip-format with XML and resources in there instead of COM structured storage files.

Answer (score 1):

1.5 MB to 69MB? Wow, that's quite a difference. If you are using a VS Setup Project check that you're not bundling the .NET Framework or any other component.

Also take a look at [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) to produce your msi packages.

Answer (score 1):

check your msi file with [Orca](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557.aspx). It will show you all the tables in the msi file, including the packed files and their sizes.

However, if you're talking about the size reported in the "add/remove programs" dialog, you should read [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/09/178342.aspx).

Comment: Link is dead. This is why we always ask people to [post answers, not links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/).

Answer (score 0):

That's extreme, I've use wix quite often but I never have seen such a big msi from small files, e.g I've something around 110 KB. So I'd think it must be due to the tools you're using. What happens if you remove the complete .msi stuff and do a complete rebuild?

Regards